# Why this print statement won´t print all the terms inside a specific taxonomy associated with a given node? (D7)

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms

I´ve tried in my Drupal 7 site with this:

```
<?php print render($content['taxonomy_vocabulary_11']); ?>
```

But it doesn´t print anything at all.
I´ve tried this too, and it prints out an error:

```
<?php print $node['taxonomy_vocabulary_11']; ?>
```

> The error is: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array
>   in /public_html/sites/all/themes/liga/templates/node--jornadas.tpl.php
>   on line 30

Using Devel, I´ve get this information, and it seems that the print statement is correct:

```
... (Array, 16 elements)
taxonomy_vocabulary_6 (Array, 16 elements)
taxonomy_vocabulary_7 (Array, 16 elements)
taxonomy_vocabulary_11 (Array, 17 elements)
#theme (String, 5 characters ) field
#weight (String, 2 characters ) 10
#title (String, 4 characters ) tags
#access (Boolean) TRUE
#label_display (String, 6 characters ) hidden
#view_mode (String, 4 characters ) full
#language (String, 3 characters ) und
#field_name (String, 22 characters ) taxonomy_vocabulary_11
#field_type (String, 23 characters ) taxonomy_term_reference
#field_translatable (String, 1 characters ) 0
#entity_type (String, 4 characters ) node
#bundle (String, 19 characters ) jornadas_realizadas
#object (Object) stdClass
#items (Array, 2 elements)
#formatter (String, 28 characters ) taxonomy_term_reference_link
0 (Array, 4 elements)
#type (String, 4 characters ) link | (Callback) link();
#title (String, 8 characters ) colegios
#href (String, 17 characters ) taxonomy/term/262
#options (Array, 2 elements)
1 (Array, 4 elements)
#type (String, 4 characters ) link | (Callback) link();
#title (String, 30 characters ) derecho
#href (String, 17 characters ) taxonomy/term/543
#options (Array, 2 elements)
```

So, the print statement should show **colegios** and **derecho**, am I right?

What´s wrong with it?

### **UPDATE**

This is the output I get with `dpm($node);`

```
(object) array(
  'vid' => '5178',
  'uid' => '1',
  'title' => 'PROYECTO',
  'log' => '',
  'status' => '1',
  'comment' => '2',
  'promote' => '0',
  'sticky' => '0',
  'nid' => '155',
  'type' => 'jornadas',
  'language' => 'und',
  'created' => '1095048000',
  'changed' => '1360589684',
  'tnid' => '0',
  'translate' => '0',
  'revision_timestamp' => '1360589684',
  'revision_uid' => '1',
  'taxonomy_vocabulary_4' => array(),
  'taxonomy_vocabulary_6' => array(
    'und' => array(
      array(
        'tid' => '33',
        'taxonomy_term' => (object) array(
            'tid' => '33',
            'vid' => '6',
            'name' => 'Jornadas Gratuitas',
            'description' => '',
            'format' => NULL,
            'weight' => '0',
            'vocabulary_machine_name' => 'vocabulary_6',
          ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'taxonomy_vocabulary_7' => array(
    'und' => array(
      array(
        'tid' => '40',
        'taxonomy_term' => (object) array(
            'tid' => '40',
            'vid' => '7',
            'name' => 'Para PH',
            'description' => '',
            'format' => NULL,
            'weight' => '-10',
            'vocabulary_machine_name' => 'vocabulary_7',
          ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'taxonomy_vocabulary_11' => array(
    'und' => array(
      array(
        'tid' => '262',
        'taxonomy_term' => (object) array(
            'tid' => '262',
            'vid' => '11',
            'name' => 'colegios',
            'description' => '',
            'format' => NULL,
            'weight' => '0',
            'vocabulary_machine_name' => 'vocabulary_11',
          ),
      ),
      array(
        'tid' => '543',
        'taxonomy_term' => (object) array(
            'tid' => '543',
            'vid' => '11',
            'name' => 'derecho',
            'description' => '',
            'format' => NULL,
            'weight' => '0',
            'vocabulary_machine_name' => 'vocabulary_11',
          ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'body' => array(
    'und' => array(
      array(
        'value' => "
```

...

Comment: you should get your print using your first command, but as you can see taxonomy_vocabulary_11 has 17 elements, dig deeper like <?php print render($content['taxonomy_vocabulary_11']['und']['0']); ?> or sth like that

Comment: Thanks, but that would mean that they all have the same term, I need a statement to print "all terms", even if it has 5 or more.

Comment: ie. I could use <?php print render($content['taxonomy_vocabulary_11'][0]['#title']); ?>, but if the node has 5 tags associated to that particular vocab I should print [1]['#title'], [2]['#title'], etc? It doesn´t make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prior to your comment you should use foreach it would be sth like this:"

```
<?php foreach ($content->taxonomy_vocabulary_11 as $key => $value): $terms = $value['#title']; ?>
    <span class="all-terms"><?php print ucwords($terms); ?></span>
 <?php endforeach?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I´ve tried that and I get this nasty error "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object".

Comment: I´ve replaced $content to $node, but I get another error "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object"

Comment: you are rendering your theme the wrong way, and its a notice, not very nasty error, try dpm($node) and paste the output here so we can take a look

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As it didn´t printed out what I wanted, it looked nasty to me :) I´ll update the question with the information. THANKS!

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617554/how-can-i-get-taxonomy-vocabulary-by-node-type

Comment: if you still didnt get your answer, use display suite module, it will do the job for you